# Copying multiple config properties in one go

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el

Assuming that I have the following properties in one of my configuration files (e.g. `application.yaml`):

```
 my.first.prefix:
   a: value-a
   b: value-b
   c:
     c1: something
     c2: something-else
```

I would want to copy over all these values to a different "prefix", e.g. to `my.second.prefix` without listing all the properties which have this prefix (i.e. without doing `my.second.prefix.a: ${my.first.prefix.a}` and so on).

The end result being that I could use this copy in a configuration of the form:

```java
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.second.prefix")
public class Config {
    private String a;
    // etc.
}
```

And I would not have to change the "copy mechanism" each time I add a new property, only the original property source and the java config.

Can this be achieved using pure SpEL? Or is this possible only programmaticaly? If so, how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can bind the `my.first.prefix` properties as usual, for example:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.first.prefix")
public class Config {
    ...
}
```

and then inject this bean in another `@Configuration` class where you can do the work of *copy*:

```
@Configuration
public class SecondConfigClass {
    @Autowired
    private Config config;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Config secondConfig(){
        Config secondConfig = new Config();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(config, secondConfig);
        // do some stuff on secondConfig's properties...
        return secondConfig;
    }
}
```

And then you can use this second config bean as usual. With this solution you keep the *.properties file simple, without the need to copy/clone/rename properties.

NB: `BeanUtils` class is part of Spring core: [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html).